# JavaScript class is not called and nothing happened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, openweathermap

I'm very new to JavaScript. I tried to use reactJS to learn a JavaScript. Here, I'm trying to develop a weather application using API. But that didn't work. Can I know what is wrong with that code.

```
class retrieveApi extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    window.alert("here");
    this.state = {
      temp: "",
      ret: "",
    };
    var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url =
      "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=API_KEY&q=california";
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
    window.alert("here");
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      if (Http.readyState == 4) {
        this.setState({
          ret: Http.responseText,
        });
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.state.ret);
        window.alert(obj.cod);
      }
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <p className="main-temp text-shadow">{this.state.temp}</p>;
  }
}
```

in my App() function I called that class like this.

```
return <div>
<retrieveApi></retrieveApi>
</div>
```

I called that class like tags. Is that right? Before I tried to create clock so I used the same so I used like this. If something is wrong please rectify it.

And When I used this things nothing shows up or changes. Please help me with it!

Comment: [Component names need to be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component), e.g. `RetrieveApi`, or react thinks you want an html element with that name., when rendering it. Which resources did you use to learn react? There are some other major flaws with the code. You shouldn't do requests or call `setState` in the constructor. Use `componentDidMount` for that.

Comment: @trixn I just random search things to learn. Can you please suggest me some resources to learn? Plesase suggest me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you're exporting your retrieveApi class and importing it properly in your app component. Assuming your app component is a functional one , this is the proper way to render a component :

```
return ( <div> <RetrieveApi></RetrieveApi></div> )
```

Notice the parantheses

Also like mentioned above , make sure to capitalize your class components.
Change :

```
class RetrieveApi
```

instead of

```
class retrieveApi
```

Answer (score 1):

Name of the class should start with capital letter. It should be RetrieveApi.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not exporting your class `retrieveApi`. Export your class like that:

`export default retrieveApi;`

Comment: When I do that It says this Line 147:1:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.

Comment: It mean you are exporting class so fix ```return ( <div> <retrieveApi></retrieveApi></div> )```